# How to reference the same object that comes from diferents streams?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an application with an api works like a web (when you ask for 'favorites' it sends a json with some elements that fit in the category, when you ask for all the elements it sends another list, which contains the favorites as well, but when the json is transformed it will be a reference of a different object).

I am trying to find the best way, not to make a call each time, storing the view in a tab and working with 'streams' instead of 'builders', but how to update the object if in a category view we assign a value to it, and when we go back to the full list tab (without reloading), show the change in the object that represents the same one that we have in favorites?

Actually I am storing the first reference of the object in a block, in an array of objects, if we first call 'favorites' the next time the same object arrives from another source, it references the first occurrence of the same object, it works, but the object list can be very large and I'm afraid maybe not the best implementation.

In a prefect world I would like not to have to store the objects and just work with the tabs loaded in streams, but I don't know how to propagate the change if the same item is on different tabs.

Any idea for a good implementation?